# Get Api Response in Azure Queue Receiver on Masstransit framework

Tags: azure, queue, azureservicebus, masstransit, azure-servicebus-queues

I am novice user of Masstransit and I am stuck very badly at one point.

Below is my architecture.

1) I have WebApi COntroller which is sending message in azure Queue using below code.

```
        if (_dipDecisionSendersEnabled)
        {
          //If MassTransit Senders are enabled, send a "ApplicationUpgradeDecision" message to the Message Bus

            Task<bool> downloading = SendDipDecisionMessagetoMessageBus(applicationNumber, 
                                                                         systemId.ToString(), 
                                                                        decisionId, externalApplicationReference);
            done = await downloading.ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        #endregion MassTransit Sender DipDecisionUpdated

        try
        {
            if (done)
            {
                response = await UpdateDIPDecision(applicationNumber, systemId, decisionId, externalApplicationReference).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
```

here what I am doing is after pushing message in queue I am calling 3rd party to update decision and get reply from them in response. This above code is in EventController class.

2) Now I have receiver as below in other file as DipConsumer.cs as below

```
        public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<DipDecision> context)
      {
        await _service.ServiceTheThing(context.Message.ApplicationNumber).ConfigureAwait(true);

            await context.RespondAsync<IMassTransit>(new
            {
                applicationNumber = $"DipDecision - Consumer Received DIP Decision for application number : {context.Message.ApplicationNumber}",
                systemId = $"DipDecision - Consumer Received DIP Decision against system : {context.Message.SystemId}",
                decisionId = $"DipDecision - Consumer Received DIP Decision against system : {context.Message.DecisionId}",
                externalApplicationReference = $"DipDecision - Consumer Received DIP Decision from external application reference number : {context.Message.ExternalApplicationReference}"
            }).ConfigureAwait(true);
      }
```

I want my consumer to be executed only when I get "Ok" as response in my response variable which is in EventController. However I am not able to inject my webapi response into receiver context.

Please guide or provide my some pointers here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To wait for a response in the API controller, you can use the Request Client, as outlined in the [documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/requests.html#container-configuration).

In essence, your controller will await the response, and then continue processing.

```
public class RequestController :
    Controller
{
    IRequestClient<CheckOrderStatus> _client;

    public RequestController(IRequestClient<CheckOrderStatus> client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> Get(string id)
    {
        var response = await _client.GetResponse<OrderStatusResult>(new {OrderId = id});

        // do the rest of the thing, based upon response.Ok

        return View(response.Message);
    }
}
```

The above linked documentation also shows how to configure the container.

If you instead want to have a separate controller method invocation, you could create a consumer that responds to an event (which the consumer you outlined above would then publish, instead of calling Respond) that would use HTTP Client to call your controller method.

Comment: This looks suitable for my case. I will update you once I am done implementing it. Thank you very much for your kind inputs.

Comment: Hello Chris, do we need to use interfaces compulsory in order to create queues over masstransit? I have removed the interfaces and instead I have got class with the necessary properties. When I made this change my queue creation works fine over azure however RabbitMQ is not creating queue over portal it does not exist. Any specific reason?

Comment: A class should work as well, just need to make sure it's public. The management console in RabbitMQ should create the exchanges for published messages. I'd suggest referring to the documentation for message design and broker topology.

Comment: ChrisSir : Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60151444/send-async-taskiactionresult-from-receiver-to-sender-in-masstrannsit