# Send async Task<IActionResult> from receiver to Sender in MASSTRANNSIT

Tags: azure, rabbitmq, masstransit, azure-servicebus-queues

I am stuck at one point in Azure ServiceBus Queue implementation using MASSTRANSIT. Below is my scenario and code.

My Sender is in EventController.cs and its code is as follow's.

```
    [ProducesResponseType(202)]
    [ProducesResponseType(400)]
    [ProducesResponseType(401)]
    [ProducesResponseType(404)]
    [HttpPut("{applicationNumber}/{systemId}/DipDecisionUpdated/{decisionId}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DipDecisionUpdated([Required]string applicationNumber, [Required]SystemEnum systemId, [Required]string decisionId, [Required][FromQuery]string externalApplicationReference)
    {
        bool done = false;
        if (!_applicationHelper.CheckApplicationAndOtherSystemReferences(applicationNumber, externalApplicationReference))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        #region MassTransit Sender for DipDecisionUpdated
        if (_dipDecisionSendersEnabled)
        {
            //If MassTransit Senders are enabled, send a "ApplicationUpgradeDecision" message to the Message Bus                
            Task<bool> downloading = SendDipDecisionMessagetoMessageBus(applicationNumber, systemId.ToString(), decisionId, externalApplicationReference);
            done = await downloading.ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        #endregion MassTransit Sender DipDecisionUpdated
        return null;            
    }
```

Now instead of return Null I want to get Consumer Reply here.

My consumer is as follow's.

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Consume and action the incoming "DipDecision" message
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<DipDecision> context)
    {
        try
        {
            var decision = await _getDecisionRepository.GetDecision(context.Message.ApplicationNumber).ConfigureAwait(false);

            int decisionInNum = 0;
            bool result = Int32.TryParse(context.Message.DecisionId, out decisionInNum);

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(decision) && decision == context.Message.DecisionId && result)
            {
                MortgageApplyApplicationStatus applicationStatus;
                switch (decisionInNum)
                {
                    case (int)UnderWritersDecision.Accepted:
                        applicationStatus = MortgageApplyApplicationStatus.Accepted;
                        break;

                    case (int)UnderWritersDecision.Referred:
                        applicationStatus = MortgageApplyApplicationStatus.UnderwriterAssigned;
                        break;

                    case (int)UnderWritersDecision.Declined:
                        applicationStatus = MortgageApplyApplicationStatus.Declined;
                        break;

                    case (int)UnderWritersDecision.NoDecision:
                        applicationStatus = MortgageApplyApplicationStatus.Declined;
                        break;

                    default:
                        applicationStatus = MortgageApplyApplicationStatus.Withdrawn;
                        break;

                }

                if (context.Message.SystemId == SystemEnum.Twenty7Tec.ToString())
                    await Update27TecApplicationStatus(context.Message.ExternalApplicationReference, applicationStatus).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            //return null;
        }

        catch (WebException we)
        {
            var exceptionCode = we.Response as HttpWebResponse;
            if (exceptionCode != null)
            {
                switch (exceptionCode.StatusCode)
                {
                    case HttpStatusCode.Accepted:
                        return Accepted();
                    case HttpStatusCode.Forbidden:
                        return Forbid(); //StatusCode(403);
                    case HttpStatusCode.BadRequest:
                        return BadRequest();
                    default:
                        return NotFound();
                }
            }
        }
        //Consumer Start from here
        await _service.ServiceTheThing(context.Message.ApplicationNumber).ConfigureAwait(true);

        await context.RespondAsync(new
        {
            applicationNumber = $"DipDecision - Consumer Received DIP Decision for application number : {context.Message.ApplicationNumber}",
            systemId = $"DipDecision - Consumer Received DIP Decision against system : {context.Message.SystemId}",
            decisionId = $"DipDecision - Consumer Received DIP Decision against system : {context.Message.DecisionId}",
            externalApplicationReference = $"DipDecision - Consumer Received DIP Decision from external application reference number : {context.Message.ExternalApplicationReference}"
        }).ConfigureAwait(true);

    }
    //Consumer Over
```

However return Accepted(), BadRequest() are showing me error as doesn't exist in context.

Also if all looks good I want to execute consumer code and it should return OK() to sender.

My consumer code is in same project but in DipDecisionConsumer.cs File.

Please help and let me know your suggestions.

Comment: Where is the message type for the response? `await context.RespondAsync(new` – should be `await context.RespondAsync<TResponse>(new`. Otherwise it's trying to send an anonymous type, which is not allowed.

Comment: By doing this I will get response on sender side?

Comment: That depends upon the behavior in the method you're calling in the controller method, but if it's using the request client to send the request, then it should yes.

Comment: I changed type to  await context.RespondAsync<Task<IActionResult>> (new ...)  There is no build error now. However on sender side instead of Return Null what code shall i write to get this response from consumer. any Git code or any reference code will be appreciated.

Comment: Task<IActionResult> is not a valid message type, it won't work. You can't serialize that over the wire. Look at the documentation for valid message types: https://masstransit-project.com/usage/messages.html